# How to completely uninstall MySQL on MacOS

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I followed another stackoverflow post to completely uninstall all instances of MySQL (I had 5..)

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
$ rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
$ sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql*
```

And reinstalled using

```
brew install mysql
```

but when I start the server, I have to put in the old root user password, which means it's still storing the passwords somewhere.

Brew prompted me change the password which I did, and then I got this error

```
... Failed! Error: File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

So clearly mysql hasn't been completely uninstalled.

Comment: What did you use to instal the original MySQL version? The data location is varying depending on how you installed it. Did you stop the MySQL server before you deleted the files? The error is an indication that the server was still running.

Comment: I can't remember, I think I downloaded it from Oracle online. I thought I did stop the server but perhaps not. How would I go about finding any left over files?

Comment: Well first thing is that you need to uninstall the brew installation using brew. Restart your Mac and check if MySQL is still running. If it is still running after the restart, then you need to figure how it was started. But it’s nearly impossible to solve that in the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay I've just uninstalled and will restart. I have the XAMP server, but it shows that the MySQL database is stopped.

Comment: Is there a command figuring out how it was started?

Comment: Well xamp shows only the status of the MySQL started with xmap. You need to check if `mysql` appears in the list  of running processes. And there is not command to figure out how it was started. You need to check the ppid of the `mysql` process. If there is still a `mysql` process after restarting, you need to figure out where the binary is located. Based Nothafen you might be able to determine how it was installed. Probably you should also uninstall xamp.

Answer (score 4):

Ended up solving it by running

```
ps -ax | grep mysql
```

then going to each of the folders and removing any mysql data

then uninstalling XAMPP

then restarting computer

then

```
brew install mysql
```

Comment: The manual removal step has to be done after you properly uninstalled mysql (or any other service) and after you ensured that it’s process is not running anymore. Otherwise is might write data back when the process is shutdown.